# iPhone SDK reachabilityWithAddress issue

Tags: iphone, sdk, reachability

I need to check connectivity with IP address only. I'm trying to do it with Apple Reachability class, using reachabilityWithAddress option. And my problem is I can put any IP address in callAddress.sin_addr.s_addr field and statusText always will be "reachble". How can I do to exactly check connectivity to IP address?

```
-(BOOL)reachabilityTest {

 struct sockaddr_in callAddress;
 callAddress.sin_len = sizeof(callAddress);
 callAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
 callAddress.sin_port = htons(24);
 callAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("212.83.3.190");
 Reachability *hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&callAddress] retain];

 NetworkStatus netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];

 if (netStatus == NotReachable)
 {
  NSLog(@"NotReachable");
  statusField.text = @"NOT reachable";
  return NO;  
 }

 if (netStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
 {
  NSLog(@"ReachableViaWiFi");
  statusField.text = @"reachable";
  return YES;
 } 
 [Reachability release];
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the Reachability classes, go old-school and open a TCP connection to it.  If the response to `connect()` is `EHOSTUNREACH`, then you can't.  If the response is `ECONNREFUSED`, or a successful connection, then you can.

Comment: It was hard to code, but it worked perfect. Thank you for an idea!

Comment: Here’s a great connect() example that worked for me: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#connect