# Reachability class returning host status as NotReachable

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to check reachability status for my server using following code:

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(80);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.21.38.120");  

Reachability *hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&address];
[hostReachable startNotifier];
```

and then checking the host status, but it is always giving status as NotReachable.
I tried to check whether the server is reachable from terminal using following command:

```
telnet Hostname port
```

and Terminal is displaying the status as connected. Is there something that i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4070754/1495678

Answer (score 0):

Try changing reachabilityWithAddress to reachabilityWithHostname.

reference : https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/issues/9
            http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2009/May/msg00056.html

Comment: I tried reachabilityWithHostName                          hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"172.21.38.120:3491"];  but then to i am not able to connect to server.

Comment: the following piece of code is working for me             hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];  but how do i connect to a particular ip address

Comment: try 172.21.38.120 without port number 3491

Comment: i tried by entering the ip address only,then to its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since upgrading to XCode 4.6 this has been an issue for me also. I can get it to work without the port - eg 10.1.1.1 works, 10.1.1.1:8000 does not. Previously both worked. Also, XCode and Simulator can cache results/values so if it's not working trying a 'Clean' or resetting your Simulator